# Compiling Latex in Java with JLatexMath

Tags: java, latex, rendering

im writing a tool in java where you should be able to render Latex code using [JLatexMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/) in version 1.0.3

Im using it like in [this example](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/page/ServerUsage/) from the documentation.

My code looks like this:

```
try{
   TeXFormula teXFormula = new TeXFormula(latex);
   TeXIcon icon = teXFormula.createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 40);
   image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
   icon.paintIcon(this, image.getGraphics(), 0, 0);
}catch(Exception exception){}
```

This code seems to work correctly, because compiling the following latex string works fine:

```
String latex = "\\begin{array}{lr}\\mbox{\\textcolor{Blue}{Russian}}&\\mbox{\\textcolor{Melon}{Greek}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mbox{" + "привет мир".toUpperCase() + "}&\\mbox{" + "γειά κόσμο".toUpperCase() + "}\\\\";
latex += "\\mbox{привет мир}&\\mbox{γειά κόσμο}\\\\";
latex += "\\mathbf{\\mbox{привет мир}}&\\mathbf{\\mbox{γειά κόσμο}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mathit{\\mbox{привет мир}}&\\mathit{\\mbox{γειά κόσμο}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mathsf{\\mbox{привет мир}}&\\mathsf{\\mbox{γειά κόσμο}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mathtt{\\mbox{привет мир}}&\\mathtt{\\mbox{γειά κόσμο}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mathbf{\\mathit{\\mbox{привет мир}}}&\\mathbf{\\mathit{\\mbox{γειά κόσμο}}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mathbf{\\mathsf{\\mbox{привет мир}}}&\\mathbf{\\mathsf{\\mbox{γειά κόσμο}}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mathsf{\\mathit{\\mbox{привет мир}}}&\\mathsf{\\mathit{\\mbox{γειά κόσμο}}}\\\\";
latex += "&\\\\";
latex += "\\mbox{\\textcolor{Salmon}{Bulgarian}}&\\mbox{\\textcolor{Tan}{Serbian}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mbox{здравей свят}&\\mbox{Хелло уорлд}\\\\";
latex += "&\\\\";
latex += "\\mbox{\\textcolor{Turquoise}{Bielorussian}}&\\mbox{\\textcolor{LimeGreen}{Ukrainian}}\\\\";
latex += "\\mbox{прывітаньне Свет}&\\mbox{привіт світ}\\\\";
latex += "\\end{array}";
```

But if i use the following latex string i get an error:

```
latex = "\n
\\begin{center}
test
\\end{center}";
```

This throws the error:

```
Unknown environment: center at position 1:0
```

I hope u can help me. Please let me know if u need more information!

Thanks

Comment: With this framework, aren't you in (TeX) math mode? Then several environments wouldn't be available. Also, what dimension should be used for linewidth? You need that for centering.

Comment: Hmm u might be right. Do you know if i can switch to LaTeX mode and if so, how i can do this?

Comment: AFAIK, within math mode you can't have things like minipage which would bring you back to full (La)TeX capabilities. I mean, the framework is meant to be good for *formulas*, not generic typesetting.

Comment: So is there any possibility to render LaTeX, not only TeX? Is there a way to switch to a LaTeX mode or something?

Comment: The class is called JLatexMath, so I'm assuming it's LaTeX, i.e., you have all the command defined in the LaTeX packages. Also, the example you've posted is clearly LaTeX.

Comment: Ok thank you, you were right. it was in math mode, i have to switch it to text mode with \\text{Text}